# What kind of jobs do people usually take during a Working Holiday, if you can't work for one employer for more than 3 months?

Tags: new-zealand, working-holiday-visas

My citizenship allows me to travel to New Zealand for a working holiday. On the surface it sounds great since salaries in NZ are very good and I could find a job easily as a software developer. However looking into the T&C it seems that you can't take a job for one employer for more than 3 months, which means most IT companies would not be interested in such an employee.

So what kind of jobs do people usually take during working holidays? Is it limited to unskilled stuff like berry picking? Is it mostly a 'holiday' rather than 'work'? Or do people simply ignore the 3 months limit and get permanent jobs all the time?

Comment: Assuming the NZ one works like the Aussie one, people aren't generally doing IT work, they're travelling/holidaying until they get low on cash, then doing whatever they find there to top up before moving on again!

Comment: Each [working holiday scheme](https://www.immigration.govt.nz/new-zealand-visas/options/work/thinking-about-coming-to-new-zealand-to-work/working-holiday-visa) has slightly different conditions depending on your country of citizenship. Also, that page says "You need to [...] be coming mainly to holiday, with work being a secondary intention."

Comment: In many cases it seems to me those are temporary works such as helping on a farm etc. Software developing will likely be a full-time job and will not likely apply in this case.

Comment: I used my WHV to do an internship, but that's a weird case. Most people seem to use them for working in farms, working in tourism (hotels, retail, and so on), or other temporary things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To post some answers from the comments:

> - Assuming the NZ one works like the Aussie one, people aren't generally doing IT work, they're travelling/holidaying until they get low on cash, then doing whatever they find there to top up before moving on again! (Gagravarr)
> - In many cases it seems to me those are temporary works such as helping on a farm etc. Software developing will likely be a full-time job and will not likely apply in this case. (JI Xiang)

So the answer is that it's only meant for non-skilled work, rather than for serious long-term jobs.